# How to make TIdIMAP4 support socks 4/5 proxy?

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

The TidIMAP4 client of the Indy package does not support socks 4/5 proxies, what will be the possible approaches to add that support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indy already has a built-in framework for connecting *any* TCP client component through a proxy. You simply attach the desired proxy component to the client component, and then the client will automatically connect to the proxy and tell it where to connect to.  And proxy components can be chained, if you need to connect through multiple proxies.

Indy 10 provides two proxy components by default - `TIdSocksInfo` for SOCKS 4/4a/5 proxies, and `TIdConnectThroughHttpProxy` for HTTP proxies (using the HTTP `CONNECT` method). But the framework is generic enough that you can derive new classes if you need to implement other proxy protocols.

In your case, before connecting to the server, assign a `TIdIOHandlerStack` component to the `TIdIMAP4.IOHandler` property, then assign a `TIdSocksInfo` component to the `TIdIOHandlerStack.TransparentProxy` property, and then configure the `TIdSocksInfo` as needed.  All of this can be done at design-time or run-time.

Comment: Great! Thanks Remy. One more thing - is there a direct method to have TIdSocksInfo use the system's proxy setting?

Comment: No. There is no such thing as "system proxy setting" to begin with. And even if there were, it would be highly platform dependent. Perhaps you are thinking of WinInet's own global proxy setting? That is not system wide. You would have to ask WinInet itself for that setting.  Otherwise, you can use protocols like Web Proxy Auto-Discovery (WPAD) to detect a proxy on the network. But either way, you would have to assign the relevant values to `TIdSocksInfo` as needed.

Comment: sorry I wasn't start implementing the socks5 until today... So I tried, and realized my TidImap4 is already have an `IOHandler` - `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL`, and this case, how to chain up with `TIdIOHandlerStack` which is another `IOHandler`? Thanks.

Comment: @EdwinYip the `TransparentProxy` property is exposed by `TIdIOHandlerSocket`, which `TIdIOHandlerStack` and `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` both derive from. IOW, you can use `TIdSocksInfo` with `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL`.